# Download PDF file inside pdfview using python/selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download a PDF from this [site](https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/enetconsulta/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?CodigoTipoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=62640) using python / selenium. When you select an option from the drop-down menu, it shows a PDF viewer. I already locate the download button, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

Ps: The print button works, but it does not solve my problem.

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(2) #seconds
print('API | Acessando ' + row[i])
driver.get(row[i]) # row[i] is the website link
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('cmbGrupo'))
select.select_by_value('PDF|1653')
#PDF|1653 - Relatorio de Adminstracao
#PDF|412 - Notas Explicativas

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
# Select frame
report= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//*[@id="iFrameFormulariosFilho"]'))
driver.switch_to.frame(report)

# Search second frame
pdfview = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//*[@id="pdfViewer"]'))
driver.switch_to.frame(pdfview)
download = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//*[@id="download"]'))
download.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use java script click.
2. Then goto download directory for verification of downloaded file.
3. Please clear download folder by using afterclass or afternethod.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(2) #seconds
print('API | Acessando ' + row[i])
driver.get(row[i]) # row[i] is the website link
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('cmbGrupo'))
select.select_by_value('PDF|1653')
#PDF|1653 - Relatorio de Adminstracao
#PDF|412 - Notas Explicativas

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
# Select frame
report= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//*[@id="iFrameFormulariosFilho"]'))
driver.switch_to.frame(report)

# Search second frame
pdfview = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//*[@id="pdfViewer"]'))
driver.switch_to.frame(pdfview)
download = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//*[@id="download"]'))
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", download

);
```

Comment: Welcome.. Gabriel